# Is there something wrong with my eclipse calculator?

Tags: eclipse

```
public class TaxReturn {
private double rate1= 0.10;
private double rate2=0.25;
private double single_limit = 32000;
private double married_limit = 64000;

private double income;
private int status;

public static int married=2;
public static int single=1;

public TaxReturn(double inc, int stat){
double income = inc;
int status=stat;
}

public double getTaxi(){
    double tax1=0;
    double tax2=0;
    if(status==single){
        if(income<=single_limit)
            tax1=rate1*income;
        else{
            tax1=rate1*single_limit;
            tax2=rate2*(income-single_limit);
        }
    }
    else{
        if(income<=married_limit)
            tax1=rate1*income;
        else
            tax1=rate1*married_limit;
            tax2=rate2*(income-married_limit);

        }
    return tax1+tax2;
}
}


import java.util.Scanner;
public class TaxCalculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("eneter income; avoid commas");
    double income = sc.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("are you married; type Y or N");
    String status=sc.next();

    int statuss;
    if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
        statuss=TaxReturn.married;
    else 
        statuss=TaxReturn.single;
TaxReturn tr = new TaxReturn(income, statuss);
System.out.println("your tax is: " + tr.getTaxi());
}
}
```

I keep getting-16000 for the answer.I dont know if my code is wrong or something wrong with the software. This code was copied from the book. Iva had this problem with other codes too. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor is not correct.
Rewrite it as follow

```
public TaxReturn(double inc, int stat){
 income = inc;
 status = stat;
}
```

By declaring type on income and status variables, you made them local to the constructor.